# replace server js files with local js for debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, fiddler

I have an application that has js file on the server, I want to be able to make changes in a local file and see how the web application responds. Someone pointed me to fiddler, but I am not sure how do I achieve that. If anyone knows any way I can achieve this, I would be really helpful. Also my js file doesnt show up in script but in network response.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can you use fiddler web debugger to intercept and modify the script? I have used fiddler before to add debugger statements to 3rd party JavaScript. It was easy.

Download fiddler and use the menu options to break on a script response. Then you can edit the script in the lower box and continue.

I will get links and more details for you.

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ Download the lastest version of Fiddler from that site. 

Once you install it and fire it up, go to the "Filters" tab on the right.  Click on the checkbox "Use Filters".  Scroll down until you see "break on content-type" and type in "text/javascript".  Fiddler will intercept the script.  When it does, on the lower left you'll see the "response" box.  You'll have the option to edit the script before clicking "run to completion".

Comment: that should be lower right for the response box, not lower left.  please forgive, first time answerer!